# Trying to order a part, shows up brake knuckle spindle assembly, but all are used for 98 civic?

Tags: honda, brakes, civic

I'm trying to order the hub assembly and brake knuckle spindle assembly for a 98 Honda Civic so that I don't have to do any press work with the bearings. On other vehicles the parts can be bought new but when you google it they are all used. Am I using the wrong name? Other vehicles it pulls it up in search engine just fine.

Comment: Front or rear ,left or right?

Comment: Front, both, but I most likely need the left. Is that what it's called. Strut assembly and trailing arm don't include it even if it was rear.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please post an answer so that this question can be moved out of the "Unanswered" category

Comment: @GettingNifty    Award yourself the answer   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up ordering the bearings separately and finding a friend who was the lead technician at a large auto shop. I had him replace my brakes, calipers and CV axles that day and it took him only a few minutes to press out the old bearings and press in the new. A professional mechanic knows an easy way to access that part.